# reading two consecutive lines from a file and print it out

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a text file which i want to get only the lines that are related to each other. tried to do this with `next()` function but didn't work out, it throws `StopIteration`. I am not sure how i can accomplish this, i appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

information below:

```
the expected output should look like this:

address-family ipv4 vrf vrf2 
 neighbor 10.244.120.202 route-map LOCAL_PREF in 
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf3
 neighbor 10.249.34.129 route-map LOCAL_PREF in
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf6
 neighbor 10.242.120.202 route-map LOCAL_PREF in 
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf9
 neighbor 10.246.88.2 route-map LOCAL_PREF in
 
>>>> text File <<<< 
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf1
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf2 
 neighbor 10.244.120.202 route-map LOCAL_PREF in 
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf3
 neighbor 10.249.34.129 route-map LOCAL_PREF in
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf5
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf6
 neighbor 10.242.120.202 route-map LOCAL_PREF in 
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf7
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf8
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf9
 neighbor 10.246.88.2 route-map LOCAL_PREF in

>>> code <<<<

with open('out_put.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith('address-family'):
            first_line = line.strip()  # strip() removes whitespace surrounding the line
            print(first_line)
            second_line = next(f).strip()
            print(second_line)
```

Comment: Please remove all the code that is not related to the actual problem (that  is, all but the last seven or so lines).  "tried to do this with next but didnt work out" -> can you clarify how it didn't work?

Comment: Extra code removed . `second_line = next(f).strip()` this is what i used but i got `StopIteration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code ensures that the file adheres to the expected format, which is that every line that does not begin with 'address-family' must be preceded by a line that does and that a line that begins with 'address-family' must be eventually followed by a line that does not begin with 'address-family'.

```
previous_line = None
with open('out_put.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('address-family'):
            previous_line = line
        else:
            if not previous_line:
                raise Exception('Unexpected file format')
            print(previous_line, end='')
            print(line, end='')
            previous_line = None
if previous_line is not None:
    raise Exception('Unexpected file format')
```

Prints:

```
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf2
 neighbor 10.244.120.202 route-map LOCAL_PREF in
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf3
 neighbor 10.249.34.129 route-map LOCAL_PREF in
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf6
 neighbor 10.242.120.202 route-map LOCAL_PREF in
address-family ipv4 vrf vrf9
 neighbor 10.246.88.2 route-map LOCAL_PREF in
```

Comment: Your code will terminate with exception, if last line of the file starts with 'address-family'. You should consider every possible scenarios.

Comment: @Liju That is precisely what it is meant to do. Read my into: " ... 'address-family' must be eventually followed by a line that does not begin with 'address-family'." So if the input ends with 'address-family' it should throw an exception. My assumption (right or wrong) is that 'address-family' *must* be matched up with a 'neighbor'. The OP would know if that is a valid assumption or not and can remove the final check.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code

```py
with open("out_put.txt","r") as f:
    line=f.readline()
    while(line):
        if line.strip().startswith("address-family"):
            line2=f.readline()
            if line2 and line2.strip().startswith("neighbor"):
                print(line,end='')
                print(line2,end='')
            line=line2
        else:
            line=f.readline()
```

Comment: You should consider the OP's text file as an example input. So:  1. What if the text file had 4 successive lines of 'address-family ... ' followed by ' neighbor '. Would your code still work? 2. Does you code actually print out what the OP wants (hint: you are calling `strip()`)?

Comment: Yes, I test run my code with OP's text file. 1.yes it works, 2.I understand. I will change it now. Thanks.

Comment: But now by not calling `strip()` you end up with an extra newline in your output. So use `print(line, end='')`.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the **.splitlines()** function and indices. If you can turn your file's lines into a list, you can use your loop-if statement to take the indice you want and then just find *that-indice*+1 and read that line as well (to get the next consecutive line).

P.S. -- if you're using standard text files, it's always good practice to add **encoding='utf-8** as the third arg of your **open()** func. This gets rid of pesky \n characters and lets the computer get more familiar with what it's actually reading.

Comment: You should consider the OP's text file as an example input. What if the input file had 4 successive lines of 'address-family ... ' followed by ' neighbor '. Would your algorithm still work?

Answer (score 0):

The next function works with iterators, in this case the file handle as already read all the file contents via readlines() function and there is nothing else to read.

You can use as below to use index to refer to the next consecutive line

```
with open('out_put.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('address-family'):
            first_line = line.strip()
            print(first_line)
            second_line = lines[i+1].strip()
            print(second_line)
```

Comment: You should consider the OP's text file as an example input. So: 1. What if the text file had 4 successive lines of 'address-family ... ' followed by ' neighbor '. Would your code still work? 2. Does you code actually print out what the OP wants (hint: you are calling `strip()`)?